# Display media file from Wordpress RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, feed

I am using the below code to grab data from a wordpress RSS feed. However I am having an issue with grabing the 'media file' from the feed.

```
<?php
        $rss = new DOMDocument();
        $rss->load('http://www.ipa.co.uk/rss/jobs');
        $feed = array();
        foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
            $item = array ( 
                'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                'image' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url'),
                );
            array_push($feed, $item);
        }
        $limit = 20;
        for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
            $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
            $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
            $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
            $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));?>
            <div class="col-md-4 job-item">
                <div class="job-item__inner">
                    <?php
                    echo '<h2 class="job-title"><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></h2>';
                    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
                    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
                    echo '<img src="'.$image.'"/>';?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923137/display-media-files-from-a-wordpress-rss-feed) on SO which helped me add in the `getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')`. However its not displaying any img src. I think 'enclosure' is correct as I get errors if I change it to something like this `getElementsByTagName('media')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')`

The issue must be that I'm targeting the wrong area of the feed. But I'm not sure what to add to get the image displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely [enable NOTICES](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) while developing with PHP. This would have led you to the answer: Your extraction code is correct but in the for-loop you need an additional line

```
$image = $feed[$x]['image'];
```

otherwise the variable `$image` is undefined n this context.

---

//edit: By the way the 2 loops are inefficient. Better use only the foreach loop and a counter. Once the counter is at 20, do a `break;`